# Please explain the following C code?

Tags: c, for-loop

When I compile and run the C code shown below, it generates the following:

Input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int a, b;

    for (j = 0; j <= 4; j+=2)
    {
        a = j;
        b = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            b += 2 * a * i;
        }

        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
   }

}
```

Output:

```
0 0

2 40

4 80
```

If anyone can tell me why the following input generates the above output, this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which part, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: What do you not understand? See also [ask].

Comment: Which language are you familiar with, so that somebody can explain with a relevant background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you understand it with the simple trace table I draw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a basic C example showing arithmetic and `printf` statements.

It helps if you break down a problem like this into modules:

1) Execute the steps 2a and 2b, with `j = 0, 2, 4`, sequentially:

```
for (j = 0; j <= 4; j+=2)
```

2a) For each index of j, `b = b + 2 * j * i` (a = j here)

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    b += 2 * a * i;
}
```

2b) `printf("%d %d\n", a, b)` is just printing out the values of j (since a is assigned the value of j) and b, where the calculations are done in step 2a.

Next time try to give the exact area where you are confused. Explaining something like this over chat is not easy. You have to break it down on your own really.